# undefined method `jobs' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm a beginner in ruby on rails and getting an error i seem not to understand.

under the  profile page for the Tradesman, i am trying to call all trades and all listed jobs under the trade. Trade has_many jobs & jobs has_many trades.

TrademanprofilesController:

```
class TrademanprofilesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = current_user   
  end

  def jobleads   
  end

  def purchased   
  end

  def memberBenifits   
  end

  def account   
  end

  def editjoblead
    @trades = Trade.order(:name)
    @jobs = Job.all

    if params[:search].present?
      @applications = Application.near(params[:search], 100, order: 'distance')
      @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@applications) do |application, marker|
        marker.lat application.latitude
        marker.lng application.longitude
        marker.infowindow application.location
        marker.infowindow application.trade.name
      end
    else
      @applications = Application.all
    end
    @applications_trades = @applications.group_by { |t| t.trade_id }   end end
```

The views page which is a partial being called elsewhere. _trademanprofile_skills.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @trades.each do |trade| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
            <%= trade.name %></br>
            <ul><% @trade.jobs.each do |job| %></ul>
                <li><%= job.name %></li>
            <% end %>
        </td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', trade %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

model: Trade.rb

```
class Trade < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :job_ids

    has_many :applications
    has_many :jobs, through: :applications
end
```

model: Job.rb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :trade_ids

    has_many :applications
    has_many :trades, through: :applications
end
```

The error i get:

```
NoMethodError in Trademanprofiles#editjoblead
undefined method `jobs' for nil:NilClass
and highlights this line: 
<ul><% @trade.jobs.each do |job| %></ul>
<li><%= job.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

i tried the below but did not work

```
<% @trades.each do |trade| %>
<%= trade.name %>
<%= trade.jobs %>
<% end %>
i got this displayed:
#<Job::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000106b0f1d8>
```

i also tried the below but did not work

```
<% @trades.each do |trade| %>
<%= trade.name %>
<%= trade.job_ids %>
<% end %>
but it only returned the id numbers of the jobs under the trade Aerial / Network 
Aerial / Network Specialist
[978, 979, 980, 1039, 1040, 1041]
```

my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :images

  devise_for :users
  resources :jobstartdates

  resources :budgets

  resources :applications do
    collection do
      get :search
      get :search_result
      get :business_details
    end
  end

  get 'home/index'

  resources :trades

  resources :jobs

  root to: 'home#index', as: 'home'

  resource :trademanprofiles do
    get :show
    get :jobleads
    get :purchased
    get :memberBenifits
    get :account
    get :editjoblead
  end

  resources :employeenumbers

  resources :businesstypes

  resources :trademanroles

  resources :titles

  resources :adverts

  resources :distances
```

i would like the Trade name & the Job names (not the ids) to be displayed. Many thanks an i truly apologise if this is a simple question.

Comment: Try this `<% @trades.each do |trade| %>` `<%= trade.job.name %>`

Comment: thanks @Pavan, unfortunately it still states the same error: NoMethodError in Trademanprofiles#editjoblead / undefined method `job' for #<Trade:0x0000010c8c1218> and highlights the line: <%= trade.job.name %>

Comment: thank you @Pavan, but still the same error: NoMethodError in Trademanprofiles#editjoblead / undefined method `jobs' for #<Trade::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0000010359ac50>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your method

```
def editjoblead
  @trades = Trade.order(:name) #this will return a collection of trades to you
  @jobs = Job.all
  #other logic
end
```

and in your view you have this

```
<ul>
  <% @trade.jobs.each do |job| %></ul>
  <li><%= job.name %></li>
  <% end %>
```

*First of all you need to correct your html you have closed `ul` and then using `li` and secondly **you are trying to get a collection on a collection(@trade is a collection and jobs will give you a collection)***

You need to do this:

```
<% @trades.each do |trade| %>
  // this will give a single trade present in @trades
  <tr>
    <td>
        <%= trade.name %></br>
        <ul>
          <% trade.jobs.each do |job| %>
            // this will give a job associated with your trade, notice it's trade and not @trade
            <li><%= job.name %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', trade %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about your routes.rb file?  I thing the error may be in there put like this in your route file

```
resources :trades do
   resources :applications
   resources :jobs 
end
```

Comment: this is completely irrelevant